# How is Text produced on the Computer?

Tags: text, binary, character

Lets say i want the text "Hello World" on my monitor, how does the computer represent, graphically, the text on the binary level?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the binary level"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a subjective question. It differs based on the hardware and potentially in application or in the OS.

In general, the hardware system you are using will have a defined text encoding that maps character images (or something similar, pixel patterns/screen colors) to given binary value(s). These images are loaded into the screen's memory buffer, which upon the next refresh is displayed on the screen.

So, in a very basic sense, let's say you have an embedded system with an LCD board. In this case it would not be images, but pixel patterns being mapped. You would likely have an 8-bit encoding that supports [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). You would load your binary values (that represent the text you want to display) into the LCD's memory/memory buffer. After the memory/buffer is loaded a command would need to be issued to the board to refresh. The display would change based on what you loaded into the memory.

If you are working very low level, then you would have to define that relationship at a driver level. Likely having to work with how to manipulate pixels via memory buffers based on binary values.

It gets more complex with say the computer you used to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you type something in your screen this is what basically happens:

1: The keyboard sends an electrical interrupt to the processor with the binary representation of the key you pressed (see [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

2: The processor looks for the memory location (which was setup by the operating system) that has the instructions to handle the interrupt

3: The interrupt is then interpreted by the operating system (let's say, Linux)

4: If there's a process waiting for input, the operating system delivers the key code to that process (let's say, Bash)

5: Bash receives the code, and sends an instruction to the operating system to display certain characters in the screen device

6: The operating system receives the instruction from Bash, and sends it to the screen device

7: The screen device receives the instruction, translates the bits into pixels and shows them in your screen

All this is abstraction. In the end, everything is binary, and if you want to get there you first should understand the abstractions (Assembly, C, Operating Systems, devices, memory, processor, etc)